# Sql Server equivalent Join update Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My update query Sql Server as follows:

```
Update Project set Name=Project.Name+' assignedTo '
FROM Project 
INNER JOIN EmployeeProject ON Project.ID = EmployeeProject.ProjectID 
INNER JOIN Employee ON EmployeeProject.EmployeeID = Employee.ID
WHERE (Employee.Name = N'Minion')
```

what is equivalent Oracle query.My try as follows:

```
Update (SELECT Project.Name as ProjectName,Employee.Name as EmpName
        FROM Project 
        INNER JOIN EmployeeProject ON Project.ID = EmployeeProject.ProjectID 
        INNER JOIN Employee ON EmployeeProject.EmployeeID = Employee.ID  
        where Employee.Name=N'Minion' 
       ) T 
set T.ProjectName=' somting'
```

But gives me error cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table.Sql server works fine.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name can you rather post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `exists`:

```
update Project p
    set Name = p.Name+' assignedTo '
where exists (select 1
              from EmployeeProject join 
                   Employee e
                   on ep.EmployeeID = e.ID
              where e.Name = N'Minion' and p.ID = ep.ProjectID 
             );
```